# Underwater point lights creating weird lighting artifacts

Tags: rendering, transparency, lighting

I have a scene set up, as shown in the image below. The water surface is a simple glass bsd shader set up to mimic water and the surface has an ocean modifier. Everyone of these six underwater lights contain a light-emitting material that is insignificant. The artifacts are produced by point lights that have a radius of 5 meters, 500W intensity and they cast shadows. TLDR; they're basic point lights beneath a glass shader.

All I want to do is simply light this pool properly, so if there's any tips in general how I can achieve better results that would be fine as well, otherwise I'm at a loss with this weird sphere around my lights.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Weird lighting under water]

Comment: can u pls provide blend file? thx

Comment: .. on https://blend-exchange.com/